# How to prove that $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$

Tags: definition, exponentiation, rational-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be rational numbers. How can I prove that
$(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$. I just don't know where to begin, can someone tell me a hint?
I know that if $a=c/d$ and $b=e/f$ then $(x^a)^b$ is ${(x^{c/d})}^{e/f}$ but then what can I do?.

Comment: Use logarithm and apply the logarithm rules. If $x>0$, then $$\begin{align}(x^a)^b=x^{ab}&\iff b\ln x^a=ab\ln x \\ &\iff ab\ln x=ab\ln x\end{align}$$

Comment: You could look at the meaning of $x^y$, when $y$ is rational.

Comment: @lonestudent This is potentially circular, since the logarithm rules are often derived from the exponential rules.

Comment: What definition of $x^a$ are you using? Also, as you don't offer a solution, the "solution-verification" tag is not appropriate.

Comment: It is worthy to note that the multiplication of the exponents applies to a real base ($x$), while in general it is not valid for a complex base

Comment: Let $x = -1, a = 2, b = \frac12$ ??? Untrue as stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to start by proving that $(x^n)^m = x^{nm}$ whenever $n, m$ are natural numbers. To do this, proceed by induction on $m$.

You would then need to extend this to the theorem that $(x^n)^m = x^{nm}$ whenever $n, m$ are integers (and both sides of the equality are defined). To do this, you need to do case analysis on the signs of $n$ and $m$ and cite the above theorem.

Then, you should extend this to rational numbers. Recall that given a rational number $\frac{n}{m}$ and a positive number $x$, the quantity $x^{n/m}$ is the unique positive  number satisfying $(x^{n/m})^m = x^n$. Using this definition, you should find it straightforward to extend the previous result to the rationals.

Comment: In case of natural powers, we can also use the definition of exponentiation and count the number of factors $x$ on both sides

Comment: @Vasya This is great for intuition, but formalising the "count the number of factors" step requires induction.

Comment: What is the "unique positive number"? Did you mean $m>0$?

Answer (score 1):

The proof depends on your definition of exponentiation. If you define $x^y$ as $\textrm{exp}(y \ln x)$ then
$$
(x^a)^b=\exp({b\ln(\exp (a\ln x))})=\exp(ba \ln x)=x^{ab}.
$$
If instead you define $x^{c/d}$ as $\sqrt[d]{x^c},$ then using the version of the law for integers,
$$
((x^{c/d})^{e/f})^{df}=\left(\left(\sqrt[f]{\left(\sqrt[d]{x^{c}}\right)^e}\right)^{f}\right)^d=((\sqrt[d]{x^c})^e)^d=((\sqrt[d]{x^c})^d)^e=x^{ce},
$$
therefore
$$
(x^{c/d})^{e/f}=\sqrt[df]{x^{cd}}=x^{\frac{c}{d}\cdot\frac{e}{f}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\mathbb R^{+}$ and ${\frac  ab}$ is a rational number, with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then $x^{\frac {a}{b}}$ is defined as:

$${x^{\frac {a}{b}}=\left(x^{a}\right)^{\frac {1}{b}}=\left(x^{\frac {1}{b}}\right)^{a}}$$

The equality on the right may be derived by putting $y=x^{\frac {1}{b}}$ and writing

$$\begin{align}\left(x^{\frac {1}{
b}}\right)^{a}&=y^{a}\\
&=\left((y^{a})^{b}\right)^{\frac {1}{b}}\\
&=\left((y^{b})^{a}\right)^{\frac {1}{b}}\\
&=\left(x^{a}\right)^{\frac {1}{b}}.\end{align}$$

If $r\in\mathbb Q^{+}$, then $0^r=0$ by definition.

All these definitions are required for extending the identity $$\left(x^a\right)^{b}=x^{ab}$$ to rational exponents.

Answer (score 0):

For my own sanity, I recently derived this in its entirety. There will be various definitions and subproofs required in order to arrive at the desired conclusion. Remember, all of the below definitions are *motivated* by properties that we *want* our power functions (and root functions) to possess. For example, we *want* it to be the case that $\forall p,q \in \mathbb Z: x^{\frac{p}{q}}\cdot x ^ {\frac{-p}{q}}=x^0=1$. To achieve this, we make sure that our definitions allow this to be so.

---

**Definition 1 $(*_1)$:** For any $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, we say that the power function $g_n$ is denoted as $g_n(\cdot)=(\cdot)^n$, where we *define* the symbol $x^n$...equivalently $(x)^n$... as meaning $x$ multiplied by itself $n$ times: $x^n=\underbrace{x \times x \times \cdots \times x}_{n \text{ times}}$

**Definition 2 $(*_2)$:** For any $r \in \mathbb R: r^0=1$

**Subproof 1 $(\star_1)$:** For any $ n \in \mathbb N: x^{n+1}=x^nx^1=x^nx$.

First, note that $x^{n}\cdot x^1$ is equivalent to writing $\left(\underbrace{x \times x \times \cdots \times x}_{n \text{ times}}\right)\cdot\left(\underbrace{x}_{1 \text{ time}}\right)$, which is obviously just $\underbrace{x \times x \times \cdots \times x}_{n+1 \text{ times}}$...i.e. $x^{n+1}=x^nx$.

**Subproof 2 $(\star_2)$:** For any $n,m \in \mathbb N : x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$.

For the base case, we have for $m=0$ that $x^{n+0}=x^n$ and $x^nx^0=x^n\cdot 1=x^n$. Let us assume that for any $m \lt m+1: x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$. We will show that $x^{n+(m+1)}=x^nx^{m+1}$. Firstly, note that $x^{n+m+1}=x^{(n+m)+1}$. By $(\star_1)$, $x^{(n+m)+1}=x^{n+m}x^1$. By assumption, $x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$, so we have that $x^{n+m}x^1=x^nx^mx^1$. Another application of $(\star_1)$ gives us that $x^mx^1=x^{m+1}$, which lets us conclude that $x^{n+m+1}=x^nx^{m+1}$.

**Proof 1 $(\dagger_1)$:** For $n,m \in \mathbb N: (x^n)^{m}=x^{nm}$.

By $(\star_1)$, we can write $(x^n)^m=\underbrace{x^n \times x^n \times\cdots \times x^n  }_{m \text{ times}}$. Next, we note that multiplication of natural numbers amounts to repeated addition. As such $nm=\underbrace{n+n+\cdots+n}_{m \text{ times}}$. We therefore have that $x^{nm}=x^{\underbrace{n+n+\cdots+n}_{m \text{ times}}}$. By repeated application of $(\star_2)$, we then have that $x^{\underbrace{n+n+\cdots+n}_{m \text{ times}}}=\underbrace{x^n\times x^n \times \cdots \times x^n}_{m \text{ times}}$. As such, $(x^n)^m=(x)^{nm}$. Additionally, if $m=0$, we can use $(\star_2)$ to easily show that $(x^n)^0=x^{n\cdot 0}$.

---

**Definition 3 $(*_3)$:** If $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, then the power function $g_{-n}(\cdot)=(\cdot)^{-n}$ is defined such that $(x)^{-n}=\frac{1}{\underbrace{x \times x \times \cdots\times x}_{n \text{ times}}}=\frac{1}{x^n}$

**Proof 2 $(\dagger_2)$:** For any $n,m \in \mathbb N:(x^{-n})^m=x^{-nm}=(x^n)^{-m}$.

By $(*_1)$ and $(*_3)$, we know that $(x^{-n})^m=\underbrace{x^{-n}\times \cdots \times x^{-n}}_{m \text{ times}}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{x^n}\times \cdots \times \frac{1}{x^n}}_{m \text{ times}}=\frac{1}{\underbrace{x^n \times \cdots \times x^n}_{m \text{times}}}=\frac{1}{(x^n)^m}$, and by $(\dagger_1)$, this equals $\frac{1}{x^{nm}}$. A direct application of $(*_3)$ shows that $x^{-nm}=\frac{1}{x^{nm}}$. Finally, by $(*_1)$ and $(*_3)$, we know that $(x^n)^{-m}=\frac{1}{(x^n)^m}$, which, by $(\dagger_1)$m is equal to $\frac{1}{x^{nm}}$.

Note that $(\dagger_1)$ and $(\dagger_2)$ mean that we can make the following claim:

> $\forall z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb Z: (x^{z_1})^{z_2}=(x)^{z_1 \cdot z_2}$

---

Before moving on, it is important to understand that any power function of the form $(\cdot)^n$ or $(\cdot)^{-n}$, where $ n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, has an inverse (note that the constant function $(\cdot)^0$ has no inverse). There are several ways of proving this, but, without straying too far from the purpose of this post, let us take it as a given that the following are true:

1. A function of the $(\cdot)^n$ form is defined for all $\mathbb R$ and is injective when the domain is restricted to either $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0]$ (if $n$ is even) or it can be injective on all of $\mathbb R$ (if $n$ is odd).
2. A function of the $(\cdot)^{-n}$ is defined on $(-\infty,0) \cup(0,\infty)$ and is injective when the domain is restricted to either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$ (if $n$ is even) or it can be injective on $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ (if $n$ is odd)

Because these two types of power functions have regions where they are injective, they necessarily have corresponding inverses that are defined appropriately; note, though, that depending on the parity and/or sign of the exponent, the inverse may be restricted to some subinterval of $\mathbb R$. For example, $(\cdot)^3$ is injective on $\mathbb R$ and has an image of $\mathbb R$; therefore, it has an inverse defined on $\mathbb R$ with an image of $\mathbb R$. The function $(\cdot)^2$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$ , strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and $(-x)^2=(x)^2$...which means that the inverse *cannot* be defined on all of $\mathbb R$. By convention, we restrict the domain of $(\cdot)^2$ to $[0,\infty)$ in the context of its inverse's definition. Because the restricted domain of $(\cdot)^2$ has an image of $[0,\infty)$, the inverse function is thus defined on $[0,\infty)$ . Similar arguments hold for the functions $(\cdot)^{-3}$ and $(\cdot)^{-2}$. Specifically, $(\cdot)^{-3}$ has a domain of $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$, is injective on this domain, and has an image of $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$. Consequently, the inverse of this function is defined on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Finally, although $(\cdot)^{-2}$ is also defined on $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$, due to the even parity of the exponent, we once again have that $(-x)^{-2}=(x)^{-2}$; this forces us to restrict the domain in the context of its inverse's definition. By convention, when determining the inverse of $(\cdot)^{-2}$, we first restrict its domain to $(0, \infty)$. On this interval, $(\cdot)^2$ is injective with an image of $(0,\infty)$. As such, the corresponding inverse function is defined on $(0,\infty)$. These 4 types of inverses cover the relevant categories across all $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$.

---

Having briefly described these inverse functions, we can now create a symbol that represents them.

**Definition 4 $(*_4)$:** If $f$ is a power function of the form $(\cdot)^z$ where $z \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, then we denote its inverse as $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{z}}$. i.e. $\left[(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{z}}\circ (\cdot)^z \right](x)=x=\left[(\cdot)^z\circ (\cdot)^{\frac{1}{z}}\right](x)$. This family of functions are known as the $n$th root functions and have the following two possible mapping rules: if $n \gt 0$: $x \mapsto (x)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{x}$ and $ x\mapsto (x)^{\frac{1}{-n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x}}$.

With the root functions established, we can now consider the composition of an arbitrary root function and an arbitrary power function. For example, if $n,m$ are natural numbers $\gt 0$, then $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{m}}\circ (\cdot)^{n}$ can be viewed as a function that maps $x\mapsto \sqrt[m]{(x^n)}$. Likewise, if $n,m \in \mathbb N$ and $\gt 0$, then $(\cdot)^{-n}\circ (\cdot)^{\frac{1}{-m}}$ can be viewed as first mapping $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{x}}$ and then mapping $\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{x}} \mapsto (\sqrt[m]{x})^n$ (i.e. the reciprocal operation caused by the negative sign acts in serial). This composition sets the need for the following subproof:

**Subproof 3 $(\star_3)$**: If $f$ is any root function of the form $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ or $(\cdot)^{\frac{-1}{n}}$, then for any $x,y \in \text{domain}(f): f(x)f(y)=f(xy)$.

Suppose $f=(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Then its inverse function is $f^{-1}=(\cdot)^n$ (perhaps with a domain restriction). As such, $f^{-1}\left(f(x)f(y)\right)=\left(f(x)f(y)\right)^n=\underbrace{f(x)f(y)\times f(x)f(y)\times \cdots \times f(x)f(y)}_{n \text{ times}}=\underbrace{f(x)\times \cdots \times f(x)}_{n \text{ times}} \times \underbrace{f(y)\times \cdots \times f(y)}_{n \text{ times}}=[f(x)]^n[f(y)]^n=[\sqrt[n]{x}]^n[\sqrt[n]{y}]^n=xy$. Obviously $f^{-1}(f(xy))=xy$. Because these functions are injective, it must be the case that $f(x)f(y)=f(xy)$.

Next, suppose $f=(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{-n}}$. Then its inverse function $f^{-1}$ is $(\cdot)^{-n}$ (perhaps with some domain restriction). As such, $f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))=(f(x)f(y))^{-n}=\frac{1}{(f(x)f(y))^n}=\frac{1}{\underbrace{f(x)f(y)\times \cdots \times f(x)f(y)}_{n \text{ times}}}=\frac{1}{\underbrace{f(x) \times \cdots \times f(x)}_{n \text{ times}}\times \underbrace{f(y)\times \cdots \times f(y)}_{n \text{ times}}}$, which is equal to $\frac{1}{f(x)^n\cdot f(y)^n}=\frac{1}{f(x)^n}\cdot \frac{1}{f(y)^n}=\frac{1}{\left(x^{\frac{1}{-n}}\right)^n}\frac{1}{\left(y^{\frac{1}{-n}}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x}}\right)^n}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{y}}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y}}=xy$. Obviously $f^{-1}(f(xy))=xy$. Because these functions are injective, it must be the case that $f(x)f(y)=f(xy)$.

A similar argument can be used to prove our 4th subproof:

**Subproof 4 $(\star_4)$**: For any $a,b \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}:\sqrt[a\cdot b]{x}=\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}=\sqrt[b]{\sqrt[a]{x}}$.

Consider the function $\sqrt[ab]{(\cdot)}$. This is the inverse function  of the power function $(\cdot)^{ab}$. As such, $(\cdot)^{ab}\circ \sqrt[ab]{(\cdot)} (x)=\left(\sqrt[ab]{x}\right)^{ab}=x$. Next, consider the two root functions $\sqrt[a]{(\cdot)}$ and $\sqrt[b]{(\cdot)}$ and their corresponding inverse functions, the power functions $(\cdot)^a$ and $(\cdot)^b$. Now, look at the following composition: $(\cdot)^b \circ (\cdot)^a \circ \sqrt[a]{(\cdot)} \circ \sqrt[b]{(\cdot)}$. Then we know that  $(\cdot)^b \circ (\cdot)^a \circ \sqrt[a]{(\cdot)} \circ \sqrt[b]{(\cdot)}(x)=\left(\left(\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}\right)^a\right)^b=x$. Importantly, though, by $(\dagger_1)$ we know that $\left(\left(\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}\right)^a\right)^b=\left(\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}\right)^{ab}$. Because $(\cdot)^{ab}$ is injective, we know that if $(\alpha)^{ab}=(\beta)^{ab}$, then $\alpha = \beta$...or, in this case, $\sqrt[ab]{x}=\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}$. A similar argument can be used to show that $\sqrt[ab]{x}=\sqrt[b]{\sqrt[a]{x}}$, which implies that $\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}=\sqrt[b]{\sqrt[a]{x}}$.

Using $(\star_3)$, we can now prove the final relevant subproof:

**Subproof 5 $(\star_5)$**: For any natural numbers $n,m \gt 0: \sqrt[n]{x^m}=\left(\sqrt[n]{x}\right)^m$

By definition, $\left(\sqrt[n]{x}\right)^m=\underbrace{\sqrt[n]{x}\times \cdots \times \sqrt[n]{x}}_{m \text{ times}} $. By repeatedly applying $(\star_3)$, we see that this is equal to $\sqrt[n]{\underbrace{x \times \cdots \times x}_{m \text{ times}}}$, which can be rewritten as $\sqrt[n]{x^m}$.

---

We can now introduce the final definition:

**Definition 5 $(*_5)$:** If $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$, then the power function $g_{\frac{p}{q}}(\cdot)=(\cdot)^{\frac{p}{q}}$ can be defined as the composition $(\cdot)^p\circ (\cdot)^{\frac{1}{q}}$ or, using $(\star_5)$, equivalently as $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{q}}\circ (\cdot)^p$...**note**, however, that there may be some domain restriction required. For example the function $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{2}}\circ (\cdot)^{-2}$ is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)\setminus \{0\}$ whereas $(\cdot)^{-2}\circ (\cdot)^{\frac{1}{2}} $ is defined on $(0,\infty)$. Nonetheless, for any $x$ common to both domains, we will have the result that $(\star_5)$ shows.

**Proof 3 $(\dagger_3)$:** If $p,q,a,b \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, then $\left(x^{\frac{p}{q}}\right)^{\frac{a}{b}}=(x)^{\frac{ap}{bq}}$.

\begin{align}\left(x^{\frac{p}{q}}\right)^{\frac{a}{b}}&=\sqrt[b]{\left(x^{\frac{p}{q}}\right)^a} \quad &&\text{ by $*_5$} \\&=\sqrt[b]{\underbrace{x^{\frac{p}{q}}\times \cdots \times x^{\frac{p}{q}}}_{a \text{ times}}} \quad &&\text{ by $*_1$} \\&=\underbrace{\sqrt[b]{x^{\frac{p}{q}}}\times \cdots \times \sqrt[b]{x^{\frac{p}{q}}}}_{a \text{ times}} \quad &&\text{ by repeated application of $\star_3$}\\&=\underbrace{\sqrt[b]{\sqrt[q]{x^p}}\times \cdots \times \sqrt[b]{\sqrt[q]{x^p}}}_{a \text{ times}} \quad &&\text{ by $*_5$}\\&=\left(\sqrt[b]{\sqrt[q]{x^p}}\right)^a \quad &&\text{ by $*_1$} \\ &=\left(\sqrt[bq]{x^p}\right)^a \quad &&\text{ by $\star_4$} \\&=\left(\left(\sqrt[bq]{x}\right)^p\right)^a \quad &&\text{ by $\star_5$}\\&=(\sqrt[bq]{x})^{ap} \quad &&\text{ by $\dagger_1$}\\&=x^{\frac{ap}{bq}} \quad &&\text{by $*_5$}\end{align}

You should be able to see that if we have $(x^{-\frac{p}{q}})^{\frac{a}{b}}$ or $(x^{\frac{p}{q}})^{-\frac{a}{b}}$, we can use $\dagger_3$ to show that the same claim holds, as well (i.e. that $(x^{-\frac{p}{q}})^{\frac{a}{b}}=(x^{\frac{p}{q}})^{-\frac{a}{b}}=(x)^{\frac{-ap}{bq}}$

Comment: Sanity, or insanity? :p